# How to build MTd projects which use MDd dlls in VS2005

Tags: linker, msvcrt, static-linking, crt

I am building my application in Visual Studio 2005, using project properties ->c/c++->CodeGeneration->RuntimeLib: MTd (using static CRT library-LIBCMTD). The application is using 3rd party dlls and libs which are built in MDd(using dynamic CRT lib- MSVCRTD).

I'm getting linker errors as:
MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll) : error LNK2005: __mktime64 already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(mktime64.obj)
MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll) : error LNK2005: __gmtime64 already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(gmtime64.obj)
MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll) : error LNK2005: __localtime64 already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(loctim64.obj)

I cannot change the 3rd party settings. My application runs fine if I use the CRT lib dynamically, but I cannot change this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is a switch to force the linker to ignore multiple definitions:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70abkas3.aspx

Comment: Is there a solution other than this? Somehow I feel it would not be safe to set this.
Thanks

Comment: Could be... but thats the only one i know. If you go with this, it would be probably best to do a build without this switch before you build an release version to check if there are any other (probably unwanted) multiple definitions beside those of the CRT library

Comment: This is extremely valuable! I've been fighting it for almost a week and I didn't know about this switch. Thank you!

(Yes, I'm aware that it's probably a quick hack, but that's what I want)

Answer (score 2):

The [/NODEFAULTLIB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tz4da4a%28VS.80%29.aspx) switch could help aswell.